# Jquery Font size resize to divs height?

Tags: jquery, html, css

Is there any way to adjust the font size to the height of an div box or an ?. I know there are many ways to adjust the font size to the width of the parent element, but i cannot find something to adjust the font size to the height.

I have several lines in a table:

```
 <table>
 <tr>
 <td> Line 1 </td>
 </tr>
 <tr>
 <td> Line 2 </td>
 </tr>
 <tr>
 <td> Line 3 </td>
 </tr>
 </table>
```

The table has an height of 100% of the viewport. SO that every td has an height of 33.33 percentage. This means the font height of every line should have 33.3% of viewport! No idee how to achieve this! Im happy about every helpful link or answer! Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you don't need to [support older browsers](http://caniuse.com/#feat=viewport-units), you could use the [new viewport-unit in CSS3](http://css-tricks.com/viewport-sized-typography/):

```
html, body {
    height: 100%;
    font-size: 100vh;
}
table {
    height: 100%;
}
td {
    font-size: 33.3%;
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/ZaJ8w/

Comment: could you explain me what the 100vh means? I never saw something like this! Thanks

Comment: 100vh = 100% of viewport height (1vh = 1%)

Comment: Jeah problem  is, i need it espacialy for android browser, but they dont support vh but thanks! I learned new things!

Answer (score 2):

Would jQuery's [height()](http://api.jquery.com/height/) work for you?

```
var height = $('td').height();
$('td').each(function() {
  $(this).css({'font-size': height + 'px', 'line-height': height + 'px'});
});
```

Comment: @Em Sta - Sorry about that. Fixed syntax error in answer. http://jsfiddle.net/UQ7Ba/

Comment: But why is the first line bigger than the other ones?

Comment: @Em Sta - The text is wrapping in the top row, making the top row in the table larger than the others.

Comment: @Em Sta - There may be some padding messing things up. Try this http://jsfiddle.net/XXuAh/.

Comment: Is there a way to change the line heigt so that all things are a little bit closer?

Comment: @Em Sta - If we get the height ahead of time, we can guarantee that all of them are the same height. See http://jsfiddle.net/XXuAh/